# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Get first and third table data

Tags: laravel, orm, model, eloquent

**Category Table**

[image]

**Service Table**

[image]

**Branch Table**

[image]

[image]

I have 3 tables link together. Above is my code, I want to produce the result same as below. Can I use a line of code to do that?

Or I have to get result from 2 tables first then only get the Branch table?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and data, not pictures of your code and data. It's much harder to help you with pictures of code than with actual code. Please read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Alright. Will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to obtain a collection of categories with service and branches you can eager load them in a single eloquent query.

```
$categories = Category::with('service.branches')->get();
```

But you still have to write a bit more if you would like to achieve your requirement.

Fractal Transformers might help you to do this. See their documentation [here](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers).

Comment: Thanks for that. It does achieve what I want.